# Setting MAX_EXECUTION_TIME on codeigniter class doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter

Putting the instruction `ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', '-1')` either at the top of the script or at the top of a time greedy function (like in the code down below) doesn't seem to work and I always get the following error:

> **Fatal error**: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded

Where should the instruction be placed?

```
public function generate_no_pass_link()
{
    ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', '-1');
    $encoder = $this->di->find('ssl_cipher');
    $storage = $this->di->find('storage');
    $salt = $storage->executeSQL("select text from translations where entity='Salt'", \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0]['text'];

    $url = 'https://mydomain/usuario/actualizar_datos/';
    $sql = "select id from clients where state=512 and created_at between  1514764801 and 1559347199";
    $result = $storage->executeSQL($sql);

    try{
        foreach($result as $id){
            $client = $storage->findOneBy('Client',array('id'=>$id));
            $link = $url . urlencode($encoder->encode($client->getEmail(), $salt));
            $client->setLogin_link($link);
            $storage->persist($client);
            $storage->flush();
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo "Links generados con éxito";
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference, but if you want to disable the timeout, you should set it to `0`. However, removing the timeout completely is rarely a good idea. It's better to give it a higher (and sensible) value. Then there at least is a timeout if something would happen.

Comment: And to add to @MagnusEriksson comment I think it would prefer the number to be an integer and not a string

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I thought so too at first but then I checked the documentation. The signature is actually: `ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue ) : string`.

Comment: whoa 300 seconds. what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You should placed it anywhere but if you put it down below on the function that can take a while, then you may get a timeout above if the script takes a long time to get to where you called it. So you have to put it on top of the script.

```
<?php ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', '-1'); 

public function generate_no_pass_link()
{
  //"Your code going here"
}
?>
```

Or you can change in the php.ini file on your server

```
/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

find this line:

```
max_execution_time = 30 //change it to -1
```

Its by default value vary from server to server. You can change it to -1